# the mean of Color [ , ] in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm new to C#, I've been searching for the meaning of "Color" in C# and find the following " Color is a struct that provides a standard way to specify and mutate colors in the C# language."  but what does

```
Color[ , ]
```

means?

for example:

```
public Color[,] TestImage_Array;
```

Comment: its a double array...basically a matrix of colors...or the coordinates of pixels in an image...do you know any other languages that have arrays in them?

Comment: `[ , ]` is nothing specific to `Color`.  It's a two dimensional array.  `[]` would be a one dimensional array

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d8d154d-5057-4dc0-bdc5-31009fc15814/object-notation-means-what?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 2):

This is a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). This would create a 2x2 array:

```
Color[,] c = new Color[2,2];
```

The syntax applies to any type and is not specific to `Color`.